# IOS 7 UIProgressView color

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I have

```
UIProgressView *progressView
```

inside a `UITableViewCell` . and when i popup `UIActionSheet` :

```
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil];

    [actionSheet addDestructiveButtonWithTitle:@"Delete" block:^(UIActionSheet *actionSheet, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
    }];

    [actionSheet addCancelButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel" block:^(UIActionSheet *actionSheet, NSInteger buttonIndex) {}];

    [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

The `progressView` change is color from the blue to gray.
Any idea how i can fix it?

Comment: You set it's `tintColor`.

Comment: Every time the UIActionSheet closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `UIProgressView`, `blueColor` is default `progressTintColor`, and `grayColor` is default `trackTintColor`. Have you make the progress changed from 1.0f to 0.0f or reload tableview?